# According to my compiler, I am using pointers incorrectly for setting values to 2D arrays. However, I am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, matrix, 2d

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
void initialize_matrices(int* a, int* b, int* c);

void fill_matrix(int* matrix);

void add_matrices(int* a, int* b, int* c);

void print_sum_matrix(int* c);


int main()
{

int a[3][3];
int b[3][3];
int c[3][3];

//Q2: define pointers (5)
//Define pointers ap, bp, and cp to the matrices that are defined above

int (*ap)[3][3] = &a; //giving the pointers a location to point to.
int (*bp)[3][3] = &b;
int (*cp)[3][3] = &c;

initialize_matrices(ap, bp, cp);

printf("Matrix a:\n");
fill_matrix(ap);

printf("Matrix b:\n");
fill_matrix(bp);

add_matrices(ap, bp, cp);

print_sum_matrix(cp);

return 0;
    }

//Q3: initialize (10)
//loop through the matrices and set each integer value to 0 using pointers
   void initialize_matrices(int* a, int* b, int* c)
 {

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) //rows
{

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) //columns
    {
        *a[i][j] = 0;   //accessing & changing the address that the pointer is pointing to?
        *b[i][j] = 0;
        *c[i][j] = 0;
    }

}

}
```

I asked a friend for advice, and they told me to change *a[i][j] = 0 to a[i * 3 + j] = 0. Is that true? If so, why do I have to do that? To my understanding, the value that a pointer is "pointing to" or at least the value of the address that the pointer is pointing to can be modified with the code that i've written above.

Comment: `change *a[i][j] = 0 to a[i * 3 + j] = 0,` this is true. but need cast `initialize_matrices((int*)ap, (int*)bp, (int*)cp);`. also If you do not want to cast needs type match. `void initialize_matrices(int (*a)[3][3], int (*b)[3][3], int (*c)[3][3])` ... `(*a)[i][j] = 0`, in this case call  `initialize_matrices(ap, bp, cp);`

Comment: Thank you for answering but will you please explain to me what that change is true? It would also be nice if you want to just link me to stuff/tell me to google certain things. I promise i've tried googling this stuff but maybe i'm just really bad at googling things.

Comment: because `ac` pass to `a` as `int *` meant  `int *a = &a(at main)[0][0]`. E.g (pointer a)[0] <=> a[0][0], (pointer a)[1] <=> a[0][1], (pointer a)[3] <=> a[1][0]

Comment: One solution is to change `void initialize_matrices(int* a, int* b, int* c)` to `void initialize_matrices(int (*a)[3][3], int (*b)[3][3], int (*c)[3][3])`, and make sure you are using `(*a)[i][j]` inside the function because `[]` has higher precedence than `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Q1, `a` is an `int[3][3]`, essentially a 3x3 matrix of integers. In the memory of your computer, this is 9 (3x3=9) integers in a single contiguous chunk of memory.

In Q2 `ap` is a pointer to an `int[3][3]`.

So when you want to set a value in the matrix through `a`, you do it like `a[i][j] = 0;`, but through `ap` you do it like `(*ap)[i][j] = 0;` Note that you need the parentheses around `*ap` here because otherwise the indexing (`[i][j]`) will happen first.

However, in Q3, when you want to pass your `int[3][3]` to a function, and then change it, it gets a bit tricky. We need to pass a pointer to be able to modify the existing matrix.

So we can either write (again, note the parentheses, they're important)

```
void initialize_matrices(int (*ap)[3][3], int (*bp)[3][3], int (*cp)[3][3]) {
    ...
    (*ap)[i][j] = 0;
    ...
}
```

We would call the function like `initialize_matrices(ap, bp, cp);` or `initialize_matrices(&a, &b, &c);`

Or we could write

```
void initialize_matrices(int *aq, int *bq, int *cq) {
    ...
    aq[j*3 + i] = 0;
    ...
}
```

In this case, we have to call the function like `initialize_matrices((int *)&a, (int *)&b, (int *)c)` - we are *casting* a pointer to an `int[3][3]` to a pointer to an integer (which may be the first one in a sequence, as it is in our case).

This is possible because, as I mentioned earlier, an `int[3][3]` is a contiguous chunk of 9 integers in memory. When you do `(*ap)[i][j] = 0;`, the computer is actually automatically doing the maths to work out which one to set, but when you cast away the information about the two dimensional array it can't do that any more, so you have do it yourself, with `[column_index*ROW_LENGTH + row_index`].

To illustrate the situation:

```
Offset : 2D Access : 1D Access
00     : a[0][0]   : 0x3 + 0 <--- my ap and aq would both point to here, but have different types
01     : a[0][1]   : 0x3 + 1
02     : a[0][2]   : 0x3 + 2
============ <- end of row 0, visual aid only, memory addresses are consecutive
03     : a[1][0]   : 1x3 + 0
04     : a[1][1]   : 1x3 + 1
05     : a[1][2]   : 1x3 + 2
============ <- end of row 1
06     : a[2][0]   : 2x3 + 0
07     : a[2][1]   : 2x3 + 1
08     : a[2][2]   : 2x3 + 2
============ <- end of row 2, end of matrix
```

If you are allowed to define the `initialize_matrices()` function however you want, I suggest the first version as you will likely find it easier to understand.

Comment: @M.M Oops. Completely slipped my mind. Less unaware and more just gigantic error on my part. Significantly edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the types right, a pointer to an array is not the same as a pointer to `int`.

Your functions just don't use 2D matrices because your interfaces are wrong. Use something like

```
void fill_matrix(int matrix[3][3]);
```

This is equivalent to

```
void fill_matrix(int matrix[][3]);
```

and

```
void fill_matrix(int (*matrix)[3]);
```

(But this "rewriting" only happens for function parameters.)

Now go from here and correct the other types that you have in your program.